# PsTricks and Png Files Shell Escape

Tags: pdf, pstricks

I am using TeXShop on Mac and want to include both pstricks graphs and an inserted image (PNG) file and I am having no luck. I have tried switching my Preferences to include Shell Escape but I am a novice and best when it comes to this. I am including the tex file and also some images.

If someone could help me step by step, I would appreciate it. I have been looking and can't figure it out.

Nick[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0SmG.png)

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uULZ.png)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{Area Between Curves}{Applications of Integrals}{BC Calculus}
\runningheader{Area Between Curves}{Applications of Integrals}{BC Calculus}
\firstpagefooter{Advisory 3}{Mr. Bennett}{SWW Math Dept.}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{center}
\psset{unit=.85cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-4)(5,6.5)
  \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!25,linestyle=none,algebraic]{%
    \psplot{0}{2}{x^2+1} 
    \psline(0,1)(2,5)(0,5)  
  }
  \psplot[linewidth=1.25pt,algebraic]{-2.25}{2.25}{x^2+1}
  \psplot[linewidth=1.25pt,algebraic]{-5}{5}{5}
  \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,arrowinset=0,arrowsize=8pt]{<->}(0,0)(-4,-3)(4,8)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
  \uput[r](1,2){$y=x^2+1$}
  \uput[u](-3.5,5){$y=5$}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
        \question For the figure above, the area of the shaded region is

        A.  $\dfrac{14}{3}$ \\ \\
        B.  $\dfrac{16}{3}$ \\ \\
        C.   $\dfrac{28}{3}$ \\ \\
        D.  $\dfrac{32}{3}$  \\ \\
        E.  $\dfrac{65}{3}$ \\ \\
\rule{7in}{1.25pt}


    \question (1998 AB 25) What is the area of the region between the graphs of $y=x^2$ and $y=-x$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$?  
        \begin{parts}
            \part 2/3
            \part 8/3
            \part 4
            \part 14/3
            \part 16/3
        \end{parts}
            \answerline
                \rule{7in}{1.25pt}

    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{graph3.png}
    \end{figure}
    \question The area of the shaded region in the figure above is represented by which of the following integrals?
        \begin{parts}
            \part $\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{c} (|f(x)|-|g(x)|\; dx}$
            \part $\displaystyle{\int_{b}^{c} f(x)\;dx}- \displaystyle{\int_{a}^{c} g(x)\; dx}$ 
            \part $\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{c} (g(x)-f(x))\;}$
            \part $\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{c}(f(x)-g(x)\;dx}$
            \part $\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{b} (g(x)-f(x))\;dx}+ \displaystyle{\int_{b}^{c} (f(x)-g(x))\;}$
        \end{parts}
            \answerline
                \rule{7in}{1.25pt}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example can not be run (uses files not generally available) but as you are using  `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` then (most) pstricks should work with pdflatex. But if using pstricks it is probably better to use latex (and not auto-pst-pdf or --shell-escape) and just convert all your png files to eps which should be easy if you have image magic or similar conversion tools

Comment: I have no problem with your example. You can run `xelatex` which doesn't need the package `auto-pst-pdf` or run `pdflatex` with option `shell-escape`. See  http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#TS

Comment: OMG that was so easy to fix. I appreciate both of you taking time to answer my question.